# Show popover without trigger

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap-3, popover

I want to show a popover without any trigger option.. I tried this but it isn't working..

```js
$('#boo').popover({
    placement : 'right',
    html : true,
    trigger : 'show', 
    content: "write sth"
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="boo" type="submit" class="btn btn-default">go</button>
```

[**update**]
I just noticed that `show` isn't listed in trigger options.. ([link](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#popovers)).. is there a way to get it work?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/nzequxtq/1/ ?

Comment: It was simpler than I thought.. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just call the `show` method

```js
$('#boo').popover({
    placement : 'right',
    html : true,
    trigger : 'show', 
    content: "write sth"
});

$('#boo').popover('show')
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.4/js/bootstrap.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.4/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<button id="boo" type="submit" class="btn btn-default">go</button>
```